# SQL to check available venues

Tags: sql

I have a table structure like:

```
 Events (id, name, start, end, venue)
 Venues (id, name)
```

Where `Events.start` and `end` are representing start and end datetimes for the event. `Events.veuue` is a foreign key to `Venues`. I want to select all available venues in a time range. What might the SQL look like. At the moment, I have difficulties figuring that out...

Comment: Which RDBMS?  Please specify.

Comment: @Shark, its SQLite, but I should be able to translate myself more or less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a `NOT EXISTS` to get rows from `Events` that don't overlap your time ranges. I think this should do the job:

```
SELECT v.id, v.name
FROM 
  Venues v 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT venue FROM Events e
  WHERE [searchdate] BETWEEN start AND end
   AND v.id = e.venue
)
```

The above uses a single datetime `[searchdate]`. If you need a start/end range of dates to check venues for, use a `WHERE` clause like:

```
WHERE 
  [searchstartdate] BETWEEN start AND end 
  OR [searchenddate]  BETWEEN start AND end
```

So, if either `[searchstartdate]` or `[searchenddate]` overlaps the event, a row will match.

Answer (score 0):

If this is MS SQL.

```
SELECT distinct Venues.id, Venues.Name
FROM Venues
INNER JOIN Events
ON Venues.id = Events.venue
WHERE @startdatetime between Events.start and Events.end
OR @enddatetime between Events.start and Events.end
```

**EDIT**
    if i understand your clarification, you need to search a venue has not been fall in between the search date.

```
SELECT distinct Venues.id, Venues.Name
FROM Venues
INNER JOIN Events
ON Venues.id = Events.venue
WHERE @searchdatetime not between Events.start and Events.end
```

Comment: I think this is checking for events happening at the venue between a given start and end datetime. I need the opposite I think. Venues where there are no events happening between the given datetime

Comment: You are not accounting for cases when events start after `@startdatetime` and end before `@enddatetime`.